# Django redirect

Tags: python, django

I have a loading page in Django while some server side processes are ongoing the view is;

```
def loading_page( request ):

    testname = request.session['testname']

    done_file = filepath_to_design_dir( testname + ".done" )


    if os.path.exists( done_file ):

        request.session["job_stat"] = "job_done"        
        return redirect( "single_output/")


    else:

        return render( request, 'single_design/loading.html' )
```

My problem is that the redirect goes to;

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/single_design/loading_page/single_output/
```

Rather than

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/single_design/single_output
```

What is the correct way to do this???

EDIT : issue resolved, thanks guys.

Urls as requested

```
from django.conf.urls import url , include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.get_single_input, name='single_design_input'),
    url(r'^single_output/$', views.single_output, name='single_output'),
    url(r'^loading_page/$', views.loading_page, name='loading_page'), 
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Could you add your `urls.py` are well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the leading slash, the current value `single_output/` is treated as a relative url, which is appended to the current url `/single_design/loading_page/` to give `/single_design/loading_page/single_output/`.

You could use the relative url `../single_output`, but I wouldn't recommend it. It would be better to return the url you want to redirect to, including a leading slash.

```
return redirect('/single_design/single_output/' )
```

Ideally, you should use the name of the url pattern, then Django will reverse it for you. Since you have,

```
url(r'^single_output/$', views.single_output, name='single_output'),
```

you can use the name instead of the url,

```
return redirect('single_output')
```

The advantage of using the name `single_output`, is that you can now change the URL in your url patterns, without having to update the view.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is not to use hardcoded link. Use [urlresolvers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

```
return redirect("some_view_name")
```